# Need help selecting url that has http:// or just //

Tags: jquery

I'm searching my dom for and iframe src that has `http://www.youtube.com` the problem is with the way I'm currently doing it it doesn't work if the url is `//www.youtube.com` which is sometimes is.

How do I convert this into something that picks up both versions of the url:

```
$youtube = $("iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']");
```

Comment: `$youtube = $("iframe[src*='//www.youtube.com']");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the "contains" attribute selector, `*=`:

```
$youtube = $("iframe[src*='//www.youtube.com']");
```

That will match both of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard selector like this:

```
$youtube = $("iframe[src*='youtube.com']")
```

That way if the iframe source contains "youtube.com" it will match, regardless of the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You could add both versions:

```
$youtube = $("iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com'],iframe[src^='//www.youtube.com']");
```

You could also use filter (the `src` property always includes the protocol):

```
$youtube = $('iframe').filter(function(){ return this.src.indexOf('http://www.youtube.com') === 0; });
```